# I am having study error in trading view pine script

Tags: pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, indicator

I am trying to create a PineScript indicator that plots a horizontal line on the chart at the 9:42 AM price of the asset being charted, during the New York trading session. It does this by first defining the 9:42 AM New York time as a series of integers using the time() function. It then creates a series of true and false values, called period, representing the time period from 9:42 AM to 9:43 AM.

Next, the code uses the ta.valuewhen() function to retrieve the 9:42 AM price. It then uses the line.new() function to draw a line at the 9:42 AM price on the chart, and the label.new() function to create a label with the 9:42 AM price at the end of the line. The appearance and style of the line and label can be customized using the input options i9Style, i9Color, and i9Label. The input option i9History determines whether the line and label will persist on the chart after the current bar (true) or be removed (false).

the issue - everything is working fine there are no error runs perfectly fine but when I add this indicator on chart it showes nothing and says : study error - can not parse resolution '09

// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/

// © Bee_Zee

//@version=5

indicator("ICT NEW YORK 9:42 AM OPEN", "ICT SAUCE 9:42 AM OPEN", true, max_lines_count=500)

i9Display = input.bool    (true, "Display", group="New York 9:42 Open")
i9Time    = input.session ('0942-0943:1234567', "Session", group="New York 9:42 Open")

i9Style   = input.string  ("Solid", "Line Style", options=["Solid", "Dotted", "Dashed"], group="New York 9:42 Open")

i9Color   = input.color   (#e43030, "Color", group="New York 9:42 Open")

i9History = input.bool    (true, "History", group="New York 9:42 Open")

i9Label   = input.bool    (true, "Show Label", group="New York 9:42 Open")

// Define the 9:42 AM New York time as a series of integers

t942 = time("09:42:00", "New York")

_9Style   = i9Style ==    "Solid" ? line.style_solid : i9Style == "Dotted" ? line.style_dotted : line.style_dashed

//==== Sauce 9:42 Open  ====
if i9Display

// Create a series of true and false values representing the time period from 9:42 AM to 9:43 AM

```
period = time >= t942 and time < t942 + 60
```

// Retrieve the 9:42 AM price using ta.valuewhen

```
price942 = ta.valuewhen(period, close, 0)
var label lb3 = na
var line lne3 = na
if price942 != price942[1]
    if barstate.isconfirmed
        line.set_x2(lne3, t942 - 30600000)

        // Draw a line at the 9:42 AM price

        lne3 := line.new(t942, price942, last_bar_time + 14400000/2, price942, xloc.bar_time, extend.none, i9Color, _9Style, 1)

        if i9Label

            // Update the label at the end of the line with the 9:42 AM price

            lb3  := label.new(last_bar_time + 14400000/2, price942, "9:42", xloc.bar_time, yloc.price, na, label.style_none, i9Color, size.normal, text.align_right)

        label.delete(lb3[1])

        if not i9History

            line.delete(lne3[1])
```

Comment: Your code is full of simple error. I tested it in Tradingview, please correct the basic errors 1 by 1, and then when you can't find why the error occurs, post the entire code in your question. Please pay attention to format correctly your question and your code.